# ModbusTcpClient cannot take source_address as argument in pymodbus module

Tags: python, modbus

Want to specify a source address for my ModbusClient with the next code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
client = ModbusTcpClient('x.x.x.x', port=502, source_address=1)
```

But recieve the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    client = ModbusTcpClient('x.x.x.x', port=502, source_address=1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source_address'
```

In [documentation](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/sync-client.html) there is defined this possability as well as class use `**kwargs` it should take any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Searching through the source code I see that they fetch the source_address like this:

`self.source_address = kwargs.get('source_address', ('', 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to the documentation source_address should be a tuple you are giving it the number 1. This source_address is then used for socket.create_connection so we can look at the python docs and see exactly what it should be:

> source_address must be a 2-tuple (host, port) for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting. If host or port are ‘’ or 0 respectively the OS default behavior will be used.
>
> -- https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection